# Tool tip over a message when mouse is moved

Tags: java, gwt, tooltip

I am trying to show a pop up box when I move the mouse over an image. Can you please help?

```
public shopWidget extends Composite implements ClickListener {
   Image phoneImage = new Image();
   Image serviceImage = new Image();
   FlexTable flTable = new FlexTable();
   flTable.setWidget(0, 0, this.rewardsLabel);
   flTable.setWidget(1, 0, this.serviceImage);
   this.initWidget(flTable);
}
```

Comment: What OS, GUI, programming language, platform, environment, etc ? Please at least tag appropriately.

Answer (score 5):

[`setTitle(String)`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html#setTitle(java.lang.String)) displays popup text over any `UIObject`, including `Image`s. This is native to the browser, and only text is allowed.

Answer (score 2):

```
    Image phoneImage = new Image();
    phoneImage.addMouseOverHandler(new MouseOverHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onMouseOver(MouseOverEvent event) {
            PopupPanel p = new PopupPanel(true);
            Widget source = (Widget) event.getSource();
            int x = source.getAbsoluteLeft() + 10;
            int y = source.getAbsoluteTop() + 10;

            p.add(new Label("hi from tooltip")); // you can add any widget here
            p.setPopupPosition(x, y);
            p.show();

        }
    });
```

here is simple [popup](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwBasicPopup) in gwt

Comment: That pop up has to fade out/disappear when mouse is moved away from the image icon pls help

Comment: See i don need Windoe.alert i have designed my owm Custom Pop up.

Comment: Let me how wil i make tat pop disapper wen i move away frm that image'

Comment: The Thing is iam able to show the pop up that pop up appearing wen i place the mouse over the image is not getting disappeared wen i mouse away its getting diassappeared if i click some where near . Gotcha

Comment: for additional methods check javadoc. That is the basis of onmouseOver handler. then you change everything to your needs

Comment: @user572598 add an `MouseOutEventHandler` to the image in which you hide the popup by calling the hide method: `p.hide()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using swing, which it doesn't look like you are, (so why am I answering?) then all JComponents implicitly support tool tips with methods such as;

```
setToolTipText(String text)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final PopupPanel pop = new PopupPanel(false, false);
pop.setWidget(new Label("popup"));
Image image = new CustomTooltipImage(pop);
image.setUrl("http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/venn-diagram.png");
```

Here is the custom tooltip image class:

```
public class CustomTooltipImage extends Image implements MouseOverHandler, MouseMoveHandler, MouseOutHandler
{
    private final PopupPanel tooltip;

    public CustomTooltipImage(PopupPanel tooltip)
    {
        super();
        this.tooltip = tooltip;
        addMouseOverHandler(this);
        addMouseOutHandler(this);
        addMouseMoveHandler(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMouseOut(MouseOutEvent event)
    {
        tooltip.hide();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMouseMove(MouseMoveEvent event)
    {
        tooltip.setPopupPosition(event.getClientX(), event.getClientY());
    }

    @Override
    public void onMouseOver(MouseOverEvent event)
    {
        tooltip.setPopupPosition(event.getClientX(), event.getClientY());
        tooltip.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `PopupPanel`?

Comment: http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/PopupPanel.html